# How in tcl to reference a variable value as an argument in an exec command (windows)?

Tags: batch-file, tcl, windows-7-x64

The tcl version I am using is 8.6. On a Windows 7 Prof system (x64), I find
something odd in the use of the exec command. I got this from reading a number of question asked before. So here goes.

When a string literal is used in the command line as

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename "c:\\somefile.bat"]
```

the batch files executes as expected. However with

```
set path "c:\\somefile.bat"
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename $path]
```

it did not execute (sometimes Windows stated it could find the file), even
if `c:\\` was the current working directory.

Not sure how to proceed.

BTW in which package is the command "`console`" included. It seems my tcl libraries installed does not include this command.

Comment: The `console` command is in the Tk package.

Comment: I have tried your code & it is working fine.

Comment: is this a case when the backslashes need escaping? Try `set path "c:\\\\somefile.bat"`. I believe that Windows is OK with unix dir separators here: `set path c:/somefile.bat`

Comment: Did any of the suggestions here help you? People doing a web search for problems like this will want to know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be all right with just

```
exec c:/somefile.bat
```

or

```
set path c:/somefile.bat
exec $path
```

Using slashes as directory separators in a script works fine even on Windows.

Documentation: [exec](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: And `file nativename` is useful for converting slash types when you need to.